# Notification when Apple compressor is done

Tags: terminal, applescript, compressor

I'm using the Apple compressor app from the command line to generate movies from sequences of images. This works fine, but the relevant command line command just exits before the job is done (while the compressor app carries out the task in the background). Hence one is left wondering when the job is finished. Using `top` I can check whether Apple compressor is still active, but I was hoping there is an option that let's me know when the job is done (ideally via osascript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a bash script that does the job. As an input it takes a directory containing the file/s to be handled by compressor. It writes the result to a predefined directory and opens the resulting file with QuickTime.

```
#!/bin/bash
input_dir=$(basename $1)
/Applications/Compressor.app/Contents/MacOS/Compressor -jobpath $1 -settingpath path_to_settings -locationpath path_to_output/$dir.mov
process_id=$(pgrep compressord) 
((while kill -0 $process_id; do sleep 1; done)  && ((pkill QuickTime || true) && open path_to_output/$dir.mov)) </dev/null &> /dev/null &
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an Automator workflow that sends a notification.
2. Set the Automator workflow as the action to use on completion.

> ### Run Automator Workflow
>
> The Automator Workflow job action applies an Automator workflow to an output file after transcoding.
>
> - Workflow: Click the Choose button to set the Automator workflow that the job action triggers.

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/compressor/cpsr6463a5b3/4.5.1/mac/10.15.6

Comment: Thanks, but the point is/was that it is unclear when the process completed. That being said, I figured it out using bash (answer below)